# Refresh the content of a list in a way that you are not adding new li but replacing with new?

Tags: javascript, html-lists

Is there a way to refresh the content of a list in a way that you are not adding new li but replacing with new?

At the moment I am trying to print from an array that has some objects with one of the property being an array itself. So each time you get randomly an object you will print it's array as well. So far I am creating list items where the items of array can be printed but each time it's adding rather than having new list item.

To be clear I want to see only the current object property inside the list not the previous. So once the new object is picked the list to be updated with the new content...

Is there a different way? I tried to change the inner html of the container div with a new list but it doesn't work....

This is what I am using but it just adds to the list rather than replacing...

```
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(quotesTags[i]));
ul.appendChild(li);
div.appendChild(ul);
```

Thank you,
Alina

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! You are simply creating the element itself (`var li`), so set the `innerHTML` of that, rather than appending a child:

```
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.innerHTML = quotesTags[i];
ul.appendChild(li);
div.innerHTML = ul;
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. I actually tired that as well but I want each item to be on separate li.

tags : [1, 2, 3]

so instead of

1 2 3

to have each time i get a new object

1

2

3

Answer (score 0):

You are already creating the `ul` and `li` as needed. The only additional thing is to create the `li`'s while iterating through the list of items. The code you need is contained in the `<script>` in the following working sample:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="test"></div>

<script>
    var quotesTags = ['apple', 'pear', 'orange'];

    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    quotesTags.forEach(function(tag) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tag));
        ul.appendChild(li);
    });
    document.getElementById('test').appendChild(ul);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thank you for the answers but what i would like to do is:

Lets say we have in html

```
<div id="test"></div> 

Then the array with the objects
var array = [
{
prop : 'first prop',
tags : [1, 2, 3]
},
{
prop : 'prop',
tags : [4, 0, 3]
},
{
prop : 'first prop',
tags : [5, 6, 8]
}
];
```

So each time a random object is selected, div will be updated with the new tags therefore the new ul.

output should be

print object
print ul for the tag

At the moment each time i print random objects, the div adds uls rather than getting a new one

I was just wondering if there is a way of attaching a NEW list to a div rather than adding...I can do it in different ways but just wanted to know if this is possible at all.